# How to parse a pandas column of JSON content efficiently?

Tags: python, json, pandas, performance

Let's say I have the following DataFrame, where the `data` column contains a nested JSON string that I want to parse into separate columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bank_account': [101, 102, 201, 301],
    'data': [
        '{"uid": 100, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 1000, "minimum": -500}, "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"uid": 100, "account_type": 2, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 2000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 0}}, "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"uid": 200, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 3000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Bob"}',        
        '{"uid": 300, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 4000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Carol"}'        
    ]},
    index = ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol']
)


df
```

I've found the `json_normalize` function, and am currently parsing the JSON in a list comprehension; the result is correct, but this takes *long*. 1000 rows take 1-2 seconds, and I have about a million rows in my real run:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

parsed_df = pd.concat([json_normalize(json.loads(js)) for js in df['data']])

parsed_df['bank_account'] = df['bank_account'].values
parsed_df.index = parsed_df['user_id']

parsed_df
```

Is there a faster way to parse this data into a nice-looking DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a small (~25%) performance improvement from bypassing `pandas.concat`.

Otherwise, rewriting / optimizing `json_normalize` doesn't seem straightforward.

```
def original(df):
    parsed_df = pd.concat([json_normalize(json.loads(js)) for js in df['data']])

    parsed_df['bank_account'] = df['bank_account'].values
    parsed_df.index = parsed_df['uid']

    return parsed_df

def jp(df):

    cols = ['account_data.currency.current', 'account_data.currency.minimum',
            'account_data.fees.monthly', 'account_type', 'uid', 'user_name']

    parsed_df = pd.DataFrame([json_normalize(json.loads(js)).values[0] for js in df['data']],
                             columns=cols)

    parsed_df['bank_account'] = df['bank_account'].values
    parsed_df.index = parsed_df['uid']

    return parsed_df

df = pd.concat([df]*100, ignore_index=True)

%timeit original(df)  # 675 ms per loop
%timeit jp(df)        # 526 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is `pd.DataFrame([...])` generally faster than `pd.concat([...])`? How much  and why? Is the memory usage about the same?

Comment: @smci, To be honest, I don't know if it's true in the general case, or if it's specific to this use case. This might be worth a new, specific question!

Comment: @Abhijeet Joshi (who doesn't have enough reputation) wanted to write:
I tried this solution but got error as "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 0):

To also automatically get the column names for the dataframe use this:

```
parsed_df = pd.DataFrame([json_normalize(json.loads(js)).values[0] for js in df['data']], columns=json_normalize(json.loads(js)).keys().tolist(), index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the JSON data is available in one big chunk rather than split up into individual strings, then using `json.loads`, iterating through the results and creating dicts, and finally creating a DataFrame on the list of dicts works pretty well. With 150,000 rows, 30 original columns and 6 columns to be extracted into a new DataFrame, it completes in less than 1 second.

For example:

```py
x = json.loads('[\
{"uid": 100, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 1000, "minimum": -500}, "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Alice"},\
{"uid": 100, "account_type": 2, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 2000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 0}}, "user_name": "Alice"},\
{"uid": 200, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 3000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Bob"},\
{"uid": 300, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 4000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Carol"}]')
load_items = []
for item in x:
  load_items.append({
    'uid': item['uid'],
    'account_type': item['account_type'],
    'currency_current': item['account_data']['currency']['current'],
    'currency_minimum': item['account_data']['currency']['minimum'],
    'fees_monthly': item['account_data']['fees']['monthly'],
    'user_name': item['user_name'], 
  })
y = pd.DataFrame(load_items)
y
```

| index | uid | account_type | currency_current | currency_minimum | fees_monthly | user_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 1 | 1000 | -500 | 13.5 | Alice |
| 1 | 100 | 2 | 2000 | 0 | 0.0 | Alice |
| 2 | 200 | 1 | 3000 | 0 | 13.5 | Bob |
| 3 | 300 | 1 | 4000 | 0 | 13.5 | Carol |

(*thanks to Jupyter/Colab for the markdown table)