# Denesting or extracting json fields from pandas DataFrame problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running into problems trying to "explode" or extracting some json fields from a Pandas DataFrame containing json columns. For example given this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [101, 102, 103, 104],
    'data': [
        '{"id": 100, "account_type": aa, "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"id": 200, "account_type": bb, "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"id": 300, "account_type": aa, "user_name": "Bob"}',        
        '{"id": 400, "account_type": cc, "user_name": "Carol"}'        
    ]}
)
```

I would like to transform `df` into this output `mydf`:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [101, 102, 103, 104],
    'account_type': ['aa','bb','aa','cc'],
    "user_name": ['alice','bob','alice','carol']
    }
)
```

As you can see, the column `data` also has an `id` column, which clashes with existing suggestions I have found in Stackoverflow. This one was promising, but it seems outdated and I get an error: [How to parse a pandas column of JSON content efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040470/how-to-parse-a-pandas-column-of-json-content-efficiently)

Error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 29 (char 28)`

Comment: Are the values for `aa`, `bb`, etc correct? The json is invalid if so, and they need to be wrapped with double quotes like `"aa"`

Comment: sorry i made a typo in the values. Anyway, I accepted the answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4908900/ezer-k as it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing quotation marks in your example and that might be the whole problem, at any rate see a full solution below, if you actually have broken json strings with unquoted aa that's a different problem

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [101, 102, 103, 104],
    'data': [
        '{"id": 100, "account_type": "aa", "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"id": 200, "account_type": "bb", "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"id": 300, "account_type": "aa", "user_name": "Bob"}',        
        '{"id": 400, "account_type": "cc", "user_name": "Carol"}'        
    ]}
)

df['data'] = [json.loads(x) for x in df['data']]
add_df = pd.json_normalize(df['data'])
add_df = add_df[[c for c in add_df.columns if c not in df.columns]]
pd.concat([df, add_df], axis=1)
```

| id | data | account_type | user_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | {'id': 100, 'account_type': 'aa', 'user_name': 'Alice'} | aa | Alice |
| 102 | {'id': 200, 'account_type': 'bb', 'user_name': 'Alice'} | bb | Alice |
| 103 | {'id': 300, 'account_type': 'aa', 'user_name': 'Bob'} | aa | Bob |
| 104 | {'id': 400, 'account_type': 'cc', 'user_name': 'Carol'} | cc | Carol |